# Create table relationships without linking them to primary key/unique

Tags: sql-server

What i'm trying to do is to link multiple tables between them without using the primary key and not being unique, but idk how to do it.

I tried using FK relationships but it does not work cause it's not unique or primary key. Hence, idk how to do it, i seek for guidance.

Here is a screenshot of my tables and how i would like to link them.[image]
Hope it helps understanding my problem.

Comment: If the value isn't unique, it seems like you're referencing the wrong object. In your diagram, however, `NOIMM` is defined as a primary key in both `SuiviMP` and `Sites` (when in combination with `Site` for the former), so can be referenced as a foreign key.

Comment: @Larnu how can i do that, owing that it's a composite key?

Comment: @Larnu I'm new to sql and everything related so don't mind my lack of knowledge

Comment: Just like you would with a single column `FOREIGN KEY`, but reference both columns. For example: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eea6dc20eba3e4be400b0046b4fd3f21)

Comment: @Larnu how do i do when a table has a cluster of 3 keys and the other a cluster of 2 keys and i have to link them?

Comment: To create a foreign key, you all the columns. If you have 2 out of 3, then you can't make a relationship, and your design is flawed (and you need to fix it).

Comment: @Larnu okay, thanks. I appreciate your help. I would review the design.